# Minio STS: provider jwt doesn't exist

Tags: jwt, wso2, minio

**solved**

---

For anyone who's trying to fix this: this error means that minio is not being able to read your `.../.well-known/openid-configuration` url*.

- (set through MINIO_IDENTITY_OPENID_CONFIG_URL or identity_openid > config_url in the json cnofig file)

---

**original post**

I'm trying to call minIO's AssumeRoleWithClientGrants, using postman I request (POST)

```
http://localhost:9000/?Action=AssumeRoleWithClientGrants&DurationSeconds=10000&Token=__SOME_TKN____&Version=2011-06-15
```

But I'm getting this response:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ErrorResponse xmlns="https://sts.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-06-15/">
    <Error>
        <Type></Type>
        <Code>InvalidParameterValue</Code>
        <Message>provider jwt doesn't exist</Message>
    </Error>
    <RequestId>163E438F6C8286CC</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

I also ran [this python example](https://github.com/minio/minio/blob/master/docs/sts/client-grants.py), and when I click on authenticate and then on approve once --WSO2-- it redirects me to an error page that says

`botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity operation: provider jwt doesn't exist`

Any help would be much appreciated,

Answer (score 1):

I got the exact same error as yours in my minio which deployed in Azure AKS. The issue was fixed by restarting the minio pod. (Looks like the minio pod was misfunctional after the AKS cluster nodes were rebooted due to the Azure DNS issue https://status.azure.com/en-ca/status)